# How can I "build" a ROS2 Python package in the ROS2 build farm?

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is/Are there (a) tutorial(s) how to integrate ROS2 packages (Python) into the [ROS2 build farm](https://ci.ros2.org/)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306295/how-can-i-%22build%22-a-ros2-python-package-in-the-ros2-build-farm?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's the same process as normal (Bloom), but with a different `rosdistro` URL.

See [Releasing a ROS 2 package with bloom](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Releasing-a-ROS-2-package-with-bloom) on the ROS2 Github wiki.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1